# Unusual behaviour of pick_event in a matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

When fig.canvas.draw() is used in onclick function, it doesn't wait for onclick event, and it comes out of the function. How to make it work continuously, so that label can be displayed every time when  clicked on the pie chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
labels = ['Beans', 'Squash', 'Corn']
def main():
    # Make an example pie plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    #labels = ['Beans', 'Squash', 'Corn']
    wedges, plt_labels = ax.pie([20, 40, 60], labels=labels)
    ax.axis('equal')

    make_picker(fig, wedges)
    plt.show()

def make_picker(fig, wedges):

    def onclick(event):
        print event.__class__
        wedge = event.artist
        label = wedge.get_label()
        print label
        fig.canvas.figure.clf() 
        ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        wedges, plt_labels = ax.pie([50, 100, 60],labels=labels)
        fig.canvas.draw()

    # Make wedges selectable
    for wedge in wedges:
        wedge.set_picker(True)

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onclick)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you please expand on your question and clearly state what you want? If you just want the label to be printed then why are you re-printing your plot?

Comment: Yes, the label is not working for the updated plot. I want it to be displayed when user clicks on pie chart, whether plot values for pie chart are modified or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `onclick` function.

```
def onclick(event):
    print event.__class__
    wedge = event.artist
    label = wedge.get_label()
    print label
    fig.canvas.figure.clf() 
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    wedges, plt_labels = ax.pie([50, 100, 60],labels=labels)
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Here you are creating new `wedges` (which overwrite your old `wedges` instances) and you are not setting them to be pickable. A quick patch for this is to change `onclick` to:

```
def onclick(event):
    print event.__class__
    wedge = event.artist
    label = wedge.get_label()
    print label
    fig.canvas.figure.clf()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    wedges, plt_labels = ax.pie([50, 100, 60],labels=labels)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    for wedge in wedges:
        wedge.set_picker(True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ya i didn't noticed that i was overwriting my old wedges instances. First i have to make the old wedges pickable and then have to make new wedges instances to be pickable. Thx :)